Box Scans in a Cartoon Warehouse
I used to be a package handler and was very slow at first. Part of the job was to find the appropriate barcode and then scan it.
I sped up a lot after realizing that if I grab opposite corners, then rotate it around that axis with the boxes about the same distance from me in my 'power zone'. By tilting it so the silhouette formed a hexagon while rotating it along that axis and moving one of the corners closer to myself, I get to see scan more of the surface area quicker than from going to one face at a time. There was the last step of making the barcode presentable once it starts to appear.
So, I was curious how to refine this method to be optimal at finding the barcode with the least amount of effort when I don't necessarily know which side the barcode is on and each successive box (cuboid) is randomly given to me.
Pseudocode

Generate the random box with a blue rectangle with a small offset along the normal so it renders correctly, but doesn't look separate.

Look at the box and find the edges.

Calculate the dimensions of the box from the silhouette

Rotate along two opposite corners that makes the largest hexagonal silhouette.

Once the barcode starts to show up change the rotation so that the path for the increase in the size of the rectangle is accelerated until it is large and clear enough to scan with a barcode scanner.


Generating the box:
randomCuboidCoordinates[] := Module[
  {x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2},
  {x1, x2} = Sort[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 2]];
  {y1, y2} = Sort[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 2]];
  {z1, z2} = Sort[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 2]];
  {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}
]
randomSurfaceRectangle[coords_] := Module[
  {x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2, face, width, height, x, y, z, rect, offset, angle, rotationMatrix, points},
  {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}} = coords;
  face = RandomInteger[{1, 6}];
  width = RandomReal[{0.5, Min[x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1] * 0.5}];
  height = RandomReal[{0.5, Min[x2 - x1, y2 - y1, z2 - z1] * 0.5}];
  offset = 0.01; (* Small offset to slightly project the rectangle outward *)
  angle = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
  
  Switch[
    face,
    1,
    x = RandomReal[{x1, x2 - width}];
    y = RandomReal[{y1, y2 - height}];
    rotationMatrix = RotationTransform[angle, {0, 0, 1}, {x + width/2, y + height/2, z1 - offset}];
    points = {{x, y, z1 - offset}, {x + width, y, z1 - offset}, {x + width, y + height, z1 - offset}, {x, y + height, z1 - offset}};
    rect = Polygon[rotationMatrix /@ points],
    
    2,
    x = RandomReal[{x1, x2 - width}];
    y = RandomReal[{y1, y2 - height}];
    rotationMatrix = RotationTransform[angle, {0, 0, 1}, {x + width/2, y + height/2, z2 + offset}];
    points = {{x, y, z2 + offset}, {x + width, y, z2 + offset}, {x + width, y + height, z2 + offset}, {x, y + height, z2 + offset}};
    rect = Polygon[rotationMatrix /@ points],
    
    3,
    y = RandomReal[{y1, y2 - height}];
    z = RandomReal[{z1, z2 - width}];
    rotationMatrix = RotationTransform[angle, {1, 0, 0}, {x1 - offset, y + height/2, z + width/2}];
    points = {{x1 - offset, y, z}, {x1 - offset, y, z + width}, {x1 - offset, y + height, z + width}, {x1 - offset, y + height, z}};
    rect = Polygon[rotationMatrix /@ points],
    
    4,
    y = RandomReal[{y1, y2 - height}];
    z = RandomReal[{z1, z2 - width}];
    rotationMatrix = RotationTransform[angle, {1, 0, 0}, {x2 + offset, y + height/2, z + width/2}];
    points = {{x2 + offset, y, z}, {x2 + offset, y, z + width}, {x2 + offset, y + height, z + width}, {x2 + offset, y + height, z}};
    rect = Polygon[rotationMatrix /@ points],
    
    5,
    x = RandomReal[{x1, x2 - width}];
    z = RandomReal[{z1, z2 - height}];
    rotationMatrix = RotationTransform[angle, {0, 1, 0}, {x + width/2, y1 - offset, z + height/2}];
    points = {{x, y1 - offset, z}, {x + width, y1 - offset, z}, {x + width, y1 - offset, z + height}, {x, y1 - offset, z + height}};
    rect = Polygon[rotationMatrix /@ points],
    
    6,
    x = RandomReal[{x1, x2 - width}];
    z = RandomReal[{z1, z2 - height}];
    rotationMatrix = RotationTransform[angle, {0, 1, 0}, {x + width/2, y2 + offset, z + height/2}];
    points = {{x, y2 + offset, z}, {x + width, y2 + offset, z}, {x + width, y2 + offset, z + height}, {x, y2 + offset, z + height}};
    rect = Polygon[rotationMatrix /@ points]
  ];
  rect
]
drawRandomCuboidWithRectangle[] := Module[
  {coords, rect, texture},
  coords = randomCuboidCoordinates[];
  rect = randomSurfaceRectangle[coords];
  texture = Texture[Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[]}]];
  Show[{Graphics3D[{
     {RGBColor[202/255, 142/255, 91/255, 1], Cuboid[coords[[1]], coords[[2]]]},
     {Blue, Opacity[1], rect}}, Boxed -> False]
  }]
]
img = drawRandomCuboidWithRectangle[] 

which gives a brown box with a blue sticker:

or this without the sticker first showing up:

Finding the Edges (partially done):
data=ImageCorners[img];
rasterizedImageEdgeDataGraph=EdgeDetect[
Rasterize[
NearestNeighborGraph[data,{4,15}]
]
,1,.25]

ridges = ImageAdjust[RidgeFilter[rasterizedImageEdgeDataGraph, .1]];
segments = FindImageShapes[ridges, "LineSegment"];
HighlightImage[rasterizedImageEdgeDataGraph, segments]

gives respectively:


And while I know segments gives the list of line segments, I don't know how to get where they are and how they relate since AdjacencyMatrix[segments] throws an error.

This is clearly related: Minimum path on a rectangular prism

I got this image. Do we need to handle cases like this?

@A.Kato No. I will fix that.

I don't know where to start because you are looking for many things at the same time. Do we have to start from 2D rasterized image? Or, can we start from Graphics3D data img as input and you just want appropriate ViewPoint for this 3D data?

@A.Kato Start from a 2D rasterized image. The thought is the robot can only see 2D pictures. Then from that picture, using a method to find the blue rectangle, or barcode, with the least amount of effort.
